# react-native : how to render state

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am having trouble rendering my `state`. The initial value of my state is `empty` but when I press the button `state change`.

I want to see this change immediately but the `state` only `renders` when start to type something in my `Textinput`

This is my State:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      noteText: '',
      userName:'',
  }
}
```

I change state using onPress button

```
changeState(){
this.setState({userName:'Kevin'})
}
```

This is where I render my State

```
    <View>
//I want to immediately render this.state.userName
       <Text>{this.state.userName}</Text>
          <TextInput
                    onChangeText={(noteText) => this.setState({noteText:noteText})}
                    value={this.state.noteText}
                    />
    </View>
```

My state won't render until I start to type something in my `TextInput`. Any idea how I can render immediately?

Comment: You can rather do `changeState=()=>{}` or `this.changeState = this.changeState.bind(this)` on your constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two ways here.

Set default state,

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      noteText: '',
      userName:'Kevin',
  }
  this.changeState = this.changeState.bind(this);
}
```

Or call `changeState` in `componentDidMount`,

```
componentDidMount(){
   this.changeState(); //bind this to changeState in constructor
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can rather use inside bind your function inside your constructor, or use the arrow function.

```js
constructor(props) {
  this.changeState = this.changeState.bind(this);
}
```

or

```js
changeState = () => {
  this.setState({ userName: "Kevin" });
};
```

Check a simple snack: https://snack.expo.io/@abranhe/change-state

[image]

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = { userName: '' };

  changeState = userName => {
    this.setState({ userName });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.username}>{this.state.userName}</Text>
        <Button title="Abraham" onPress={() => this.changeState('Abraham')} />
        <Button title="James" onPress={() => this.changeState('James')} />
        <Button title="Mark" onPress={() => this.changeState('Mark')} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  username: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
});
```